# How to set an Index when creating a document with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

On the frontend of my app, the user is able to fill in a small form with his/her work experience. He's also able to dynamically add fields to this to add more work experience. In case you're not getting me, here's a [GIF](https://gyazo.com/ea4c1e2e506752d14d6a7710a1d4a620).

Before sending that form to the server, I convert everything into a `FormData` object. Considering I got a user that dynamically adds 1 form on top of the default one, this is what get's send to the server:

**FIRST Work Experience**

`["company", "companyA"]`

`["positionExperience", "positionA"]`

`["descriptionExperience", "descriptionA"]`

**SECOND Work Experience**

`["company", "companyB"]`

`["positionExperience", "positionB"]`

`["descriptionExperience", "descriptionB"]`

---

On the backend of my app I got a post route to post the form to that looks like this:

```
personRoutes.post('/new', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    const person = new Person({
        file: req.file.path,
        experience: [
            {
                company: req.body.company,
                positionExperience: req.body.positionExperience,
                descriptionExperience: req.body.descriptionExperience,
                websiteExperience: req.body.websiteExperience,
                timeperiodExperience: req.body.timeperiodExperience,
            }
        ],
    });
    person.save()
        .then()
        .catch()
});
```

**The problem** is that `req.body` on the server side, pushes the answers on both forms in an array. To demonstrate what I mean, this is a `console.log` of the `req.body`

```
BODY:  [Object: null prototype] {
   company: [ 'companyA', 'companyB' ],
   positionExperience: [ 'positionA', 'positionB' ],
   descriptionExperience: [ 'descriptionA', 'descriptionB' ],
}
```

So In my post route I somehow have to specify an **index** for the experience fields. Does anyone know how I would have to go about that? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Share the code where you build the `FormData` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The problem is that req.body on the server side, pushes the answers on both forms in an array. "*

That's not actually correct, as it is in fact the **client** request which is actually being sent like that. Basically that's the default for `x-www-form-urlencoded` data when you submit *more than one value* for a provided field name, and it sends what is interpreted as *arrays* for each field, instead of an *array of submissions* in the way you are expecting.

Seems more to me like you could be submitting the data in a more suitable format ( i.e a pre-structed JSON representation of the object you actually want ), but in lieu of actually changing the code which submits the form you could always just transform what is sent into a reasonable representation of what you want to actually insert for a new `Person`.

Presuming of course that the only data present in `req.body` is related to the `experience` part of the data to be added then a simple statement transforms this in the *array* of entries you actually want, rather than just *all fields as arrays* as they currently are:

```
let data = req.body;

// For each total array length of a required field
let experience = [ ...Array(data.company.length)]
  Get all the keys of the input object  
  .map((e,i) => Object.keys(data)
    // Turn that into an object of singular values for the current index
    .reduce((o,e) => ({ ...o, [e]: data[e][i] }),{})
  )
```

IF however you have more data in `req.body` and only want a set of specific fields, then that's just a simple modification with a `Array.filter()`. Runs in the browser from within this post this time:

```js
   // Just simulating the content submitted in req.body
   let req = {
     body: {
        "company" : [
                "companyA",
                "companyB"
        ],
        "positionExperience" : [
                "positionA",
                "positionB"
        ],
        "descriptionExperience" : [
                "descriptionA",
                "descriptionB"
        ]
      }
    };
 

    // list of allowed fields
    let whitelist = [
      'company',
      'positionExperience',
      'descriptionExperience',
      'websiteExperience',
      'timeperiodExperience'
    ]

    // Remove all but the wanted fields
    let data = Object.entries(req.body)
      .filter(([k,v]) => whitelist.indexOf(k) != -1)
      .reduce((o,[k,v]) => ({ ...o, [k]: v }),{});

    let experience = [ ...Array(data.company.length)]
      .map((e,i) => Object.keys(data).reduce((o,e) => ({ ...o, [e]: data[e][i] }),{}))

    console.log(experience)
```

Either where those were the only keys of the input `req.body` or where you extracted only what you wanted via the alteration directly above, the output `experience` array is then ( as based on the sample data shown in the question to be added not how intended ):

```
[
        {
                "company" : "companyA",
                "positionExperience" : "positionA",
                "descriptionExperience" : "descriptionA"
        },
        {
                "company" : "companyB",
                "positionExperience" : "positionB",
                "descriptionExperience" : "descriptionB"
        }
]
```

Which basically means that `experience` can simply be transposed into your existing code as follows:

```
const person = new Person({ file: req.file.path, experience });
```

Then of course what will be saved will reflect that same structure:

```
{
  "file": "whateverFileNameSupplied",
  "experience": [
        {
                "company" : "companyA",
                "positionExperience" : "positionA",
                "descriptionExperience" : "descriptionA"
        },
        {
                "company" : "companyB",
                "positionExperience" : "positionB",
                "descriptionExperience" : "descriptionB"
        }
  ]
}
```

---

Personally I would probably build more *smarts* into the front end in order to actually submit the data in a format I really want. But what you have with arrays on each property is actually typical of a standard `x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request, and if you don't yet want to spend the time in submitting a JSON request which actually aligns with what you want to store, then a transformation like above is generally your shortest path to getting it done.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks A LOT for your very well written answer. It took me about a day to fully understand everything you wrote. I took your advice to heart and went to work on building in *smarts* on the frontend. I went with converting the file to ```FormData```. For the array of objects I went with:
```let experience = JSON.stringify(this.person.personData.experience);```
```formData.append('experience', experience);``` 

Was fairly easy to parse it on the backend. Thanks again, really helped me a lot :)